# const static member initialization - inside vs outside class definition

Tags: c++, stl

I know that static literal type members can be initialized in the class definition, and non-literal types can't.

```
class Class 
{
    static const int lt = 0; //OK
    static const std::string nlt = "hello"; //compilation error
};
```

However, I ran into a weird issue, where I can't use the members in STL containers if they are initialized inside the class definition, as opposed to outside.

```
class Class
{
public:
    static const int var = 1;
    void f();
};

void Class::f() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(var);
}
```

The example above results in the linker error `undefined reference to Class::var` If I move the initialization outside, the error goes away.

`const int Class::var = 1;`

What are the differences between the two initializations above? Why does one cause the error with stl containers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the differences between the two initializations above? Why does one cause the error with stl containers?

The argument type of `std::vector<int>::push_back()` is `int const&`. Whenever a variable is used by reference or pointer, it must be defined.

A simple change to `Class::f` implementation will obviate the need to define `Class::var`.

```
void Class::f() {
   std::vector<int> vec;
   int v = var;
   vec.push_back(v);
}
```

Here, `var` is not used by reference. Hence, there is no need to define `Class::var`.

Comment: Thanks. Also, defining it outside the class with the initialization in the declaration works `const int Class::var;` This allows the clarity of the values in the header, but it can still be referenced.

Comment: As well, creating a temporary `vec.push_back((int)var)` is pretty readable, and doesn't need the definition.